# Force all programs to use the full OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog interfaces instead of FolderBrowserDialog when opening/saving files?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, windows-8

Here's a question I don't think has been asked before.

**Background:** I hate the `FolderBrowserDialog` GUI component with a fiery passion. You know, the useless little folder tree view dialog which some programs insist on using to select files or folders? It looks like this:

[image: die]

If possible, I would like **all programs** to be effectively blocked from using this terrible little dialog and instead be forced to use the regular `OpenFileDialog` instead. It looks like this:

[image]

Also, I don't know what this variant of the `SaveFileDialog` is called, where the left-hand pane is replaced with those obnoxiously large icons, but I hate it too. If possible I'd also like to banish it from all programs and have it replaced with the "normal" `SaveFileDialog`, above. It looks like this:

[image]

Is any of this possible using some kind of system-wide hook/intercept or is it just a pipe dream?

Comment: 1. Browse for folder is a shell dialog. File Open is a common dialog. Different product teams. 2. Office doesn't use Windows' dialogs. They use their own. Any answer won't apply to Office. 3. To change appearance ONLY you would need to write a dll, inject into all processes, hook the API call, change the flags for appearance. A very advanced undertaking.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamea and see flags.

Comment: Are there any "real" programs that use the BrowseForFolder dialog? I use it in scrpts because it's the easiest to add, but don't recall seeing it in a stand-alone program.

Comment: Its purpose is to choose a folder in Internet Explorer 4 / Desktop Update (bringing IE features to the Win 95 style desktop ie Active Desktop).

Comment: @KeithMiller This also marked the change from Office driving Windows user interface (toolbars, context menus, etc) to Internet Explorer driving Windows user interface (Active Desktop items embedded in a html desktop).

Comment: @user1292580: Not sure what you're trying to say. I'm asking the OP when/where he is seeing the BrowseForFolder dialog.

Comment: short answer: you are not going to get what you are looking for. sorry. I was writing a program just the other week, and was surprised that there really isn't anything better for this task built in. Note that neither the open file dialog or save as will let you select a folder. I ended up getting a package off nuget. either way, the dialog in use is selected by the developer when they are writing the program, and you cannot change its behavior via system configuration. I sympathize, I hate FolderBrowseDialog as well, largely because it never works for network locations.

Comment: @KeithMiller Honestly I can't remember what I was using the last times I've encountered this. I think mostly it's installers for freeware utilities and stuff like that. Maybe PortableApps.com installers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a pipe dream.

No, you can't force a program to make a different API call because you don't like the one it made.

I realize that these essentially accomplish the same thing but the arguments and parameters are completely different between these two interfaces.

In addition, a programmer can customize the dialog that appears depending on which interface is called.

Comment: Thought so. Thanks. Just out of interest, any idea what the two different versions of the "Save As" dialog as featured in my screenshots are called?

Comment: The first one (that you don't like) is called a [FolderBrowserDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=net-5.0) and you can tell by the c# default icon that it is being called from c#.  The second one is called a [SaveFileDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=net-5.0).  Both dialogs have been there since Windows95.  SOME of what sucks  is that programmers can limit the functionality using flags to launch the thing.. for instance, not showing things windows can see on the network.

Comment: What's the third one called? Also a SaveFileDialog but with different flags to show the large icons on the left?

Comment: I believe that it is the older version of the same dialog.  It looks like XP and possibly Vista..  I looked at the flags for the API call and nothing jumped out at be but I bet it is in there.

Comment: It's not just in XP/Vista. The dialog is still in use on Windows 10, for example in Photoshop CS5's save dialog. (I still hate it.)